# Why is the candlestick chart so weird

Tags: python, matplotlib, finance

[image: Candlestick chart - 5mins chart]

```
df['DateTime'] = df['Date'] +' '+ df['Time']
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

df['ohlcDate'] = df.DateTime.map(mdates.date2num)

ohlc = df[['ohlcDate','Open','High','Low','Close']]
print(ohlc)
f1, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,9))
candlestick_ohlc(ax, ohlc.values, width=.6, colorup='cornflowerblue', colordown='violet')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H%M'))
plt.show()
```

[image: 5mins chart data]

Do you guys know why the candlestick chart is weird like this?

Comment: What do you mean by weird

Comment: @Agile_Eagle. It's weird all right. The real question is what was OP expecting instead?

Comment: @MadPhysicist you are right

Comment: It's impossible to copy and paste that image of the data. Please post text as text, formatted as code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 1):

Your candles are `0.6` days (i.e. ~14 hours) wide. However looking at the data, you would probably rather like them to be `0.03` days (i.e. ~45 minutes) wide. Hence use

```
width=0.03
```

or whatever number suits you well in this case.